# Add input and check input for the next few times

Tags: jquery

Add input and check input for the next few times for emptiness, and if one of them is empty then do not add a new input. How can you add input when you first click and check them for emptiness on the next and if one of the added inputs is empty then do not add the next one?

```
<label class="button">New</label>
  <div class="table-title">
    <div class="table_narrow">Name</div>
    <div class="table_narrow">Amount</div>
    <div class="table_narrow">Time</div>
</div>
<div class="table-list">
</div>
```

Function itself

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    $(".table-list").prepend('<div class="table-row">' +
        '<input class="table-list" name="Name[]" type="text">' +
        '<input class="table-list" name="Amount[]" type="number">' +
        '<input class="table-list" name="Date[]" type="date">' +
        '<label class="table-btn></label>' +
        '</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search all the existing inputs before prepending.

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    var empty_found = false;
    $(".table-list input").each(function() {
        if (this.value == "") {
            empty_found = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    if (empty_found) {
        alert("Fill in all rows before adding another row");
    } else {
        $(".table-list").prepend('<div class="table-row">' +
            '<input class="table-list" name="Name[]" type="text">' +
            '<input class="table-list" name="Amount[]" type="number">' +
            '<input class="table-list" name="Date[]" type="date">' +
            '<label class="table-btn></label>' +
            '</div>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check all first row inputs, if any, for unfilled ones. The code uses `.filter()` to count the unfilled (empty) inputs.

```js
$(".button").click(function () {
    //Get all first row inputs, if any (see inputs.length)
    var inputs = $('div.table-row:first input');
    
    //If inputs found, get number unfilled, otherwise 0
    var numUnfilled = inputs.length ? inputs.filter(function() {
        return !this.value.length;
    }).length : 0; 
    
    //If numUnfilled is zero, add row; otherwise do not add row
    numUnfilled ||
    $(".table-list").prepend('<div class="table-row">' +
        '<input class="table-list" name="Name[]" type="text">' +
        '<input class="table-list" name="Amount[]" type="number">' +
        '<input class="table-list" name="Date[]" type="date">' +
        '<label class="table-btn></label>' +
        '</div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="button">New</label>
  <div class="table-title">
    <div class="table_narrow">Name</div>
    <div class="table_narrow">Amount</div>
    <div class="table_narrow">Time</div>
</div>
<div class="table-list">
</div>
```